# redis-cli: using "-r -1" exits immediately instead of running command indefinitely

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, ping, amazon-elasticache, redis-cli

I'm trying to monitor the behavior/uptime of a Redis cluster (on AWS ElastiCache) while performing various maintenance operations on it. According to [this doc](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) (under "Continuously Run Same Command"), I should be able to use the "-r" flag with the argument "-1" to run a command continuously. However, when I run my PING command with this option, it terminates immediately with no output but the status code indicates success:

```
$ root@00460dccc7d9:/data# redis-cli -h my-host.txz1ua.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com -r -1 -i 1 PING
$ root@00460dccc7d9:/data# echo $?
0
```

If I use other numbers, it works as expected:

```
root@00460dccc7d9:/data# redis-cli -h my-host.txz1ua.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com -r 3 -i 1 PING
PONG
PONG
PONG
root@00460dccc7d9:/data#
```

Anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, it appears that there is a regression in redis-cli with regards to this feature. I've opened a corresponding [issue in the repo](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/6117).